# Camera command/accessibility in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera

What would be the command and where is located in order to use the phone's camera capabilities?

I want to create a camera based application, and as a beginner, I don't know how to put it in the application. I have activated the ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA from the WMAppMAnifest.xml so the access to the hardware is granted, but I can't find the command or string to integrate in my app.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorial should help you create your application sucessfully !

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx

It applies to both Windows Phone 8 and 7.1 as well

Also , you can read about the main Camera API from here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.photocamera(v=vs.105).aspx

Good Luck !

Comment: thank you very much. I will look over those articles and hopefully I will make it. I may need some further indications so please stay tuned ;)